# Regular expression for complicated email

Tags: regex, email

I want an regex for email that starts with numbers and letters.

My regex is

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/
```

What is wrong in this? It allows `._-` from start and in between. But I don't want this

Valid emails = `s@gmail.com`, `s.p@y.com`, `s_p123@g.com`

Invalid emails = `....s@g.com`, `s---g@g.com`, `s...@g.com`, `44s..p@g.com`, `----s@g.com`

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Are you aware that TLDs may have much more than 4 character length? See: http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Comment: http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/

Answer (score 1):

So you dont want to have more than one `._-` in your regex? And also it shall not start with `._-` Try it this way:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[._-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]*@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}
```

It works for your examples, although im not really sure what email-syntax you really want to test for.

Perhaps you want to use one of many pre written examples in the web (just google ;) )

Comment: Thats good. If the answer solves your problem please mark it as accepted :D